# Encoders debouncing with 7414 at 3.3V

Tags: encoder, button, schmitt-trigger, debounce

I'm trying to make a small module that has 2 rotary encoders (both have build-in push buttons), hardware debouncing circuit and have to be compatible with both 5.0V and 3.3V microcontroller logic inputs.

What I've found, that most typical schematic involves the inverting Schmitt trigger (74HC14 or 74LS14) and should be looks like:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2feMT3W.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The D1 could be omitted since it is just for decreasing charging time of capacitor C1.

Could you help me with questions:

1) Will 74HC14 (74LS14) work with 3.3V input?

2) Could 74HC14 (74LS14) use the 3.3V as power supply?

3) Could 74HC14 (74LS14) produce the 3.3V output to be connected with STM32F103**** (or other 3.3V logic level microcontoller)

Or should I use the SN74LV14A instead of 74HC14 (74LS14)? Looks like SN74LV14A is more suitable for lower voltages.

Comment: The 7414 datasheets:
http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/sn54ls14-sp.pdf
https://www.calstatela.edu/sites/default/files/groups/Department%20of%20Electrical%20and%20Computer%20Engineering/labs/7414.pdf

Comment: 74LV*14 datasheets:
http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/sn74lv14a.pdf
https://assets.nexperia.com/documents/data-sheet/74LVT14.pdf

Comment: I'm sorry for adding datasheets as comments, but I don't have enough reputation to post more than 2 links in post.

Comment: You provided a link to a 74HC14, while calling it a 7414. Which do you mean, 74HC14 or 7414?

Comment: Yes, 74HC14. As is in original post: "involves the inverting Schmitt trigger (74HC14 or 74LS14)"

Comment: Which is it, 74HC14 or 74LS14? There is a difference, and it matters in this case.

Comment: Which one of those will work both for 3.3V and 5.0V? 
There is a typo in first comment. It should looks like this:
74HC14 datasheet: http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/sn74hc14.pdf
74LS14 datasheet: http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/sn54ls14-sp.pdf

Comment: What do the data sheets say about power supply limits? I'm not going to do your work for you, especially when this information is so well-described on the data sheets.

Comment: Look at the Recommended Operating Conditions for the supply voltage are you within the min and max?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want the 74HC14. The HC series will operate at your 3.3 Vcc. The LS will not.

For your questions 1-3, yes to all for the HC series.